# Not able to load an image in the webpage using mod_python

Tags: html, mod-python

I have to make a webpage using mod_python, i have to load an image on the webpage this is the code that i have made

```
import cgi
import nltk
import time

    def fill():
       s = """\
    <html><body bgcolor="777777" >
    <form method="get" action="./show">
    <p>Type a word: <input type="text" name="word">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"</p>
    </form>
    <img width="640" height="480" src="simplify.jpg" />
    </table>
    </body></html>
    """
       return s
```

It has to load image but its not doing so.. what is the problem?? I couldn't get any good tutorials, if any one could suggest me a link it will be very helpful..

Comment: just fyi, mod_python is pretty much dead, despite what it says on the website. just in case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you use apache2 mod python. There must be a function called def index which receives at least one parameter which is the request. The result of this function will be passed to the client.

So in your case something like:

```
def index (req):
       s = """\
    <html><body bgcolor="777777" >
    <form method="get" action="./show">
    <p>Type a word: <input type="text" name="word">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"</p>
    </form>
    <table height="200" width="300"
     background="/var/www/cgi-bin/simplify.jpg" >
    <img width="640" height="480" src="simplify.jpg" />
    </table>
    </body></html>
    """
       return s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) :) its working :) :) If u could send me any good links for mod_python tutorials it will be of great help :) )

Comment: Actually this is everything you need. Maybe when using HTML-forms, you can just add the parameters to your index parameter list and the handler takes care of filling these in.

Comment: Oh you mean to say, consider i need two images to be loaded then i have to return 2 parameters? If you have time can you give one such example with 2 images please??

Comment: You can only return one item. If your script RECEIVES parameters from e.g. a web form, then it will RECEIVE more params.

Comment: It would be of more help if you could explain with an example :-/ If u are busy then no problem :)